# java function to check if the sum is even or odd, why does my code not work?

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my code, which did not cause any error but it doesn't give the result.

I wrote a  function which checks if the sum of all numbers of the array is even or odd :

```
package tests;

public class Test {

public static String oddOrEven(int[] array) {

    int X = 0;
    String y;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {

        X += array[i]; // this is line 12
    }
    if (X % 2 == 0) {
        y = "even";
    } else {
        y = "odd";
    }
    return y;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {


    oddOrEven(new int[] {
        4,
        8,
        9,
        64,
        21,
        7
    }); // this is line 25

}
```

}

The exception I am seeing:

[image]

please help.

thank you

Comment: If an array `[a,b,c]` has size `3` then it has the mappings `[0=a,1=b,2=c]` Do you see how you might have gone over that number?

Comment: If your question has typos then edit it.

Comment: thank you, could u please correct my code what should i change ?, i am a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your for-statement to this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //this line was wrong by you, use '<' instead of '<='
        X += array[i]; 
    }
```

You are using this operator `<=` rather than `<`, so when you get to the size of the array (`6`) you are trying to retrieve an array element with index `6`, whilst index `5` is your highest.

Comment: thank you so much it worked

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a little index problem and added some formatting and a output:

```
public static String oddOrEven(int[] array) {

    int X = 0;
    String y;
    int i;
    //i needs to be smaller than the size as indexes start with 0(not with 1) 
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        X += array[i];// this is line 12
    }
    if (X % 2 == 0) {
        y = "even";
    } else {
        y = "odd";
    }
    return y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String result = oddOrEven(new int[]{4, 8, 9, 64, 21, 7});// this is line 25
    System.err.print(result);

}
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition of the loop to either `i < array.length` or `i <= array.length-1`. 
When you use `.length` on an array it will return the number of elements in the array(if there is 1 element in an array it will return 1). But indexing starts at 0. So you can get the first element, by running `array[0]`, but if you run `array[1]` you will get "Array index out of bounds exception".